# When is a Noetherian Standard graded algebra over a field Cohen-Macaulay? Any counter-example when it is not the case?

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a Noetherian standard graded algebra with $R_0 = k$, a field, then it is finitely generated over $R_0$ by $R_1$ and is the homomorphic image of some $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, hence isomorphic to $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$ where $I = (a_1, \ldots, a_s)$ is a homogeneous ideal of height $g$.

When is a Noetherian standard graded algebra over a field Cohen-Macaulay? Any easy counter-example(s) when it is not the case?

Edit: A standard graded algebra not CM is $k[x,y]/(x^2, xy)$, which has dim = 1 but depth 0.

Comment: Try $k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$.

Comment: Most properties/results for local rings hold verbatim in the standard graded case by adding the word "graded" everywhere, and Cohen-Macaulay is no exception

Comment: @Mohan This does not seem standard graded though.

Comment: What is your definition of standard graded?

Comment: @Mohan An $\mathbb{N}$-graded Noetherian $A$-algebra $R$ is called standard if $A = R_0$ and it is generated over $R_0$ by $R_1$.

Comment: My ring is one such where $R_1$ is the four dimensional vector space generated the four monomials above.